# Pentaho PDI || Windows Current User

Tags: etl, pentaho, pdi

**PDI Version**: 9.3

**Environment**: Windows Server

I'm trying to retrieve the username of the current user executing the transformation, with the aim of creating dynamic file paths based on this user information.

I used the "Get System Info" step:

- Hostname (Real): Give me the server name
- Hostname (Network Setup): Give me the server name

I was not able to get the current user how is executing the transformation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the step `Add constant` to add a shell command as String and then use the `Execute a process` step to execute it (The step execute the command for each row).

For windows you can use the command `cmd.exe /C echo %USERNAME%` to get the current user.

[Transformation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKwUl.png)

You'll get the result on `Result output` field.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It gave me error "Cannot run program "cmd.exe /echo %USERNAME%": CreateProcess error=2. The system cannot file the file specified.

Comment: On your error, it seems that you missedtype the command make sure it's : `cmd.exe /C echo %USERNAME%`
You can also try it like this : `cmd /c echo %USERNAME%`

Comment: Thank you so much, @Omegad. However, the solution worked in local PC; however, in the server side the solution did not work because of the security policy. Please is there another way to get the current user ?